# ClassNotFound Expection when loading beans in Grails

Tags: spring, grails, grails-2.0

I have a jar file which has the beans defined in applicationContext.xml. I have added the jar file to the lib directory and also modified my build config to

> runtime "content:content-examiner-data:1.0"

I have defined the beans in the resource.groovy as follows

> beans = {
>
> ```
> importBeans("classpath*:/applicationContext.xml")
> ```
>
> }

The bean definitions are as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" />


    <bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate"
        id="mongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg value="documents"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="database" mongo-ref="mongo"/>
  <mongo:mapping-converter id="converter" />

  <bean id="gridTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg ref="converter" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="ceMongoStore" class="gov.ic.isso.ce.service.mongoimpl.CEStorageMongoImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoTemplate" />
    <constructor-arg ref="gridTemplate" />
    <constructor-arg value="cedocs" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

I get an error as follows when running the app with run-app option

```
 Error 2013-02-07 16:08:24,806 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Cannot find class [gov.ic.isso.ce.service.mongoimpl.CEStorageMongoImpl] for bean with name 'ceMongoStore' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/development/projects/sentrytrunk/Latest/fc/content-examiner-web/lib/content-examiner-data-1.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gov.ic.isso.ce.service.mongoimpl.CEStorageMongoImpl
Message: Cannot find class [gov.ic.isso.ce.service.mongoimpl.CEStorageMongoImpl] for bean with name 'ceMongoStore' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/development/projects/sentrytrunk/Latest/fc/content-examiner-web/lib/content-examiner-data-1.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gov.ic.isso.ce.service.mongoimpl.CEStorageMongoImpl
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ClassNotFoundException: gov.ic.isso.ce.service.mongoimpl.CEStorageMongoImpl
->> 202 | run      in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
```

when I do a dump of the jar file using jar tvf I get the following output

```
1472 Thu Feb 07 16:00:30 EST 2013 applicationContext.xml
   709 Thu Feb 07 16:00:30 EST 2013 gov/ic/isso/ce/data/CEStorage.class
  1946 Thu Feb 07 16:00:30 EST 2013 gov/ic/isso/ce/data/model/document/Document.class
  1186 Thu Feb 07 16:00:30 EST 2013 gov/ic/isso/ce/data/model/document/DocumentStatus.class
  5995 Thu Feb 07 16:00:30 EST 2013 gov/ic/isso/ce/service/mongoimpl/CEStorageMongoImpl.class
     0 Thu Feb 07 16:00:34 EST 2013 META-INF/maven/
     0 Thu Feb 07 16:00:34 EST 2013 META-INF/maven/gov.ic.isso.content-examiner/
     0 Thu Feb 07 16:00:34 EST 2013 META-INF/maven/gov.ic.isso.content-examiner/content-examiner-data/
  1925 Thu Feb 07 15:54:44 EST 2013 META-INF/maven/gov.ic.isso.content-examiner/content-examiner-data/pom.xml
   146 Thu Feb 07 16:00:34 EST 2013 META-INF/maven/gov.ic.isso.content-examiner/content-examiner-data/pom.properties
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `runtime "content:content-examiner-data:1.0"` or the jar file - you only need one. If you add jar files to the lib directory, you need to run `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` to get it added to the classpath

Comment: that doesn't fix it. Still seeing the error. Is there any other way to laod the beans in grails ?

Comment: Found the issue, I don't know why spring was throwing this error when the actual cause was something else.